# Disable transparent div at the time of page loading & want to show after page load

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have made a transparent div which has some text over this div to show to make it more bright. But the problem is at the first time of loading the page this div is loading first , which is not looking good,So I just want that this div should load later at when all other content of page  has loaded .

My div code in css

```
#abc {
    position:absolute;
    top:228px;
    width:852px;
    height:160px;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    border-radius:8px;
    }
```

And I am using it in my view I am using it as

```
<div id="abc">
    <h1><?php echo Configure::read('SearchBarHeading');?></h1>
    <h2><?php echo Configure::read('SearchBarSubheading');?></h2>
</div>
```

So how can I make it hidden first & show it later when page has loaded

Comment: You can use `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` To run code when the page has loaded. So make it hidden at first, then execute a show in the ready function.

Answer (score 1):

Hide it with CSS and then display it using jQuery

CSS

```
#abc {
    position:absolute;
    top:228px;
    width:852px;
    height:160px;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    border-radius:8px;
    display: none;
    }
```

jQuery JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#abc').show();  // or you can use .fadeIn()
});
```

Comment: HI Vector thanks for quick response ,but this code is not working ,I had already try this , what happening while using it div  & content in it all become hidden and not showing on screen after window load ,So I just want to hide this div at window loading & want to make visible after window load completly

Comment: This code would make the content visible once the Jquery runs. Ensure you have the jQuery library included